# How to use a custom scheduler for kubernetes (on google cloud), written in bash language?

Tags: kubernetes

at http://blog.kubernetes.io/2017/03/advanced-scheduling-in-kubernetes.html an example of a custom scheduler for kubernetes is given, which is written in bash language. 
My question is how can such a custom scheduler be used for a pod? 
It says "Note that you need to run this along with kubectl proxy for it to work", which is not clear to me.

I would appreciate any help.
thanks

Comment: By the way, I need to use such a custom scheduler to assign pods to the nodes in a google cloud cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to deploy the scheduler. Then associate that scheduler to your pod.

This is a great write-up: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/

Here is an example deployment of `my-scheduler`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    component: scheduler
    tier: control-plane
  name: my-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: scheduler
        tier: control-plane
        version: second
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /usr/local/bin/kube-scheduler
        - --address=0.0.0.0
        - --leader-elect=false
        - --scheduler-name=my-scheduler
        image: gcr.io/my-gcp-project/my-kube-scheduler:1.0
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10251
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
        name: kube-second-scheduler
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10251
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: '0.1'
        securityContext:
          privileged: false
        volumeMounts: []
      hostNetwork: false
      hostPID: false
      volumes: []
```

Here is how to connect a pod to your scheduler:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: annotation-second-scheduler
  labels:
    name: multischeduler-example
spec:
  schedulerName: my-scheduler
  containers:
  - name: pod-with-second-annotation-container
    image: gcr.io/google_containers/pause:2.0
```

The key part in the above are `spec.schedulerName`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I'm new to kubernetes and sorry if my questions are basic.

Comment: Does it mean that I need to build an image from the scheduler, i.e.  from my scheduler that is written in bash language? and then use that in the deployment?

Comment: It would appear so. Looks like schedulers are deployments that sit in the kube-system namespace. This example might help: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/plugin/pkg/scheduler. And more specifically: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/plugin/pkg/scheduler/scheduler.go

Comment: Since you want pods on specific nodes, can you simply use label selectors? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/. For instance you can create a label for your node, e.g. google-cloud. Then use a nodeSelector on your pod specification to ensure that it's deployed to that node.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can use labels to assign the labeled pods to the nodes with matching labels, but I also need another property. I need the pods with label A to run on at most n nodes with matching labels.

Comment: So I thought I need a customized scheduler that counts the number of nodes on which the pods with label A are running, and if that number becomes equal to the specific n then it assign next pods of that type to one of those already used nodes randomly (to keep the number of used nodes by those pods less than or eqal to n).

Comment: How many different pod types do you need to do this for? If it's only a small number, then simply perform the partitioning manually. That is, create another label `google-cloud-a` and assign it to `n` of nodes at random (simple script). Then use the nodeSelector to ensure that pods labeled as 'a' are assigned to that sub-set of nodes.

Comment: I understand your point and will go for that if I cannot figure out how to build a custom scheduler.